# Spring Boot: enable HTTP TRACE method for embedded Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, spring-boot, http-trace

Standalone Tomcat allows you to enable TRACE HTTP method through `allowTrace` attribute:

> allowTrace - A `boolean` value which can be used to enable or disable
>   the TRACE HTTP method. If not specified, this attribute is set to
>   `false`.

If I have to do that same for a Spring Boot project using embedded Tomcat - what kind of config/properties setting I can use for that?

I have looked for the properties supported by Spring Boot for Tomcat server:

[image: properties supported by spring boot for tomcat server]

but it seems to be not listed. Any thoughts how to achieve this.

Answer (score 4):

You can configure `Connector.allowTrace` property programmatically. In this case you have to define bean for class [`EmbeddedServletContainerFactory`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/EmbeddedServletContainerFactory.html) and add connector customizer by calling [`TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.addConnectorCustomizers(...)`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/context/embedded/tomcat/TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory.html#addConnectorCustomizers-org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatConnectorCustomizer...-) method. It allows you to access [`Connector`](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/api/org/apache/catalina/connector/Connector.html) object and call any configuration method you need. In this case we simply call `connector.setAllowTrace(true)`:

```
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.tomcat.TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
public class TomcatConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public EmbeddedServletContainerFactory embeddedServletContainerFactory() {
        TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory factory = new TomcatEmbeddedServletContainerFactory();

        factory.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> {
            connector.setAllowTrace(true);
        });
        return factory;
    }
}
```

You can configure this bean in a separate configuration class (like in the example above) or you can simply add this bean method to your main Spring Boot application class.

#### Couldn't it be done with `server.tomcat.*` like property?

At this moment - nope. Current Spring Boot version (`1.5.9-RELEASE`) does not allow to set it up with a simple property. All properties with `server.tomcat` prefix are mapped automatically to class [`org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ServerProperties.Tomcat`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/ServerProperties.Tomcat.html). If you take a look at its javadocs (or source code in your IDE) you will see that there is no method like `setAllowTrace(boolean value)` or something like that.

Comment: I appreciate your answer which is quite possible on spring... but at the same time does a simple application.properties based property exist for this...

Comment: @samshers Nope, at this moment you cannot set this value with `server.tomcat` prefixed property. I've updated an answer to explain why it is not possible.

Comment: that's its... gr8.

Comment: @samshers I'm glad I could help you :) Good luck!

Answer (score 4):

The solution above only works for Spring Boot 1. For Spring Boot 2 the following works:

```
    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> tomcatCustomizer() {
        return customizer -> customizer.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> {
            connector.setAllowTrace(true);
        });
    }
```

If you want to apply if on the managemant port you need to create a configuration class that looks something like this:

```
@ManagementContextConfiguration
public class ManagementInterfaceConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebServerFactoryCustomizer<TomcatServletWebServerFactory> tomcatCustomizer() {
        return customizer -> customizer.addConnectorCustomizers(connector -> {
            connector.setAllowTrace(true);
        });
    }

}
```

and a resource (=on the classpath) in `META-INF/spring.factories` that picks it up:

```
org.springframework.boot.actuate.autoconfigure.web.ManagementContextConfiguration=\
com.package.ManagementInterfaceConfiguration
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to enable TRACE Http Method you can extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` like this:

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Bean
public HttpFirewall configureFirewall() {
    StrictHttpFirewall strictHttpFirewall = new StrictHttpFirewall();
    strictHttpFirewall
      .setAllowedHttpMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST","PUT","DELETE","OPTIONS","TRACE"));
    return strictHttpFirewall;
}
}
```